# What should happen when Face ID is turned off after having been used?

Tags: password, development, ui, face-id

I can't find anywhere in Apple's guidelines what the behavior of Face ID should be in the following scenario:

1. I enter valid credentials
2. I enable Face ID
3. I use Face ID to log in (for some period)
4. I return to the login screen and disable Face ID
5. I reenable Face ID

As a convenience having 5 use the credentials supplied in 1 makes sense (doing otherwise would be frustrating), but what if between 4 and 5 I enter new credentials (e.g. I've changed my password or I need to use a different e-mail address). In that case having 5 use the credentials supplied in 1 no longer makes sense.